# What does Any() mean in this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, any

What is the `Any()` doing in the following query?

```
context.Customers
    .Include("InternetSales")
    .Where(c => c.InternetSales.Any())
    .Take(100);
```

How would you read out this query in plain English? For example, would the following be accurate?

> *"Get customers with their associated 100 internet sales."*

(I know there is no "get" in the code, but you get what I mean.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Any` operator checks whether some enumerable / collection contains at least one item, i.e. whether it is non-empty.

So I guess your query could read as:

> "the first 100 customers that have made at least one internet sale"

or, somewhat closer to the metal:

> "the first 100 `Customer` objects that have a non-empty `InternetSales` collection"

`.Any()` is similar to `.Count() > 0`, but it will consume at most one item in the collection, while `Count` consumes the complete collection, so `Any` is generally more efficient and works for infinite sequences, too. Provided you're not interested in the exact number of items, `Any` also expresses the intent of checking for non-emptiness more clearly.

Comment: Perhaps a NotEmpty() synonym would be nice :)

Comment: @NetMage: IMHO, it is far easier to intuitively understand the meaning of `customers.Any()` than of `customers.NotEmpty()`. With the latter, I will have to keep my brain from puzzling about the concept of non-empty customers: "Are they like milk bottles, i.e. they can be empty or full or something in-between?" OTOH, with `customers.Any()`, the intended meaning is immediately obvious: "Are there any customers?"

Comment: @NetMage: Or, phrasing it differently, `customers.Any()` focuses on what `customers` represents (a group of customers), while `customers.NotEmpty()` focuses on what `customers` technically is (a collection object). The former point of view is usually more valuable to understanding what the code means. (Again, IMHO.)

Comment: The fact that the first line of your answer explains .Any() in terms of non-empty makes me think otherwise :)

Comment: @NetMage: You are right to a certain extent, and I guess I could improve my answer there. I added the above two comments quite some time after writing the original answer, and have probably learnt some things since then.

Comment: @NetMage: I think it's important to distinguish between the explanation of a LINQ operator's *function* and the explanation for its *name*. Any *generally valid* explanation of a LINQ operator's *function* must necessarily rely on the same general abstraction that all things LINQ share: `IEnumerable` collections. Which is why my answer correctly gives a technical explanation. The *naming* of an operator OTOH is an entirely different matter: There's no reason that an operator's name cannot go beyong the technical POV; a name that leads to intuitive, easy-to-read code should be preferred.

Comment: To beat a dead horse, since customers is "a group", whether a group is non-empty seems to me more understandable than "a group".Any which doesn't seem to have a sensible interpretation. We are not asking Customer.Any but rather Customers.Any.